make4ht LaTeX to HTML: how to scale some figures relative to page size and some in absolute size
I converted some LaTeX documents to HTML using TeX4ht with the make4ht wrapper.
I provide image sizes as follows in my LaTeX
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}

and use the option Gin-percent as described here to convert these into sizes relative to the page width in the HTML. I use the following command
make4ht myfile.tex "Gin-percent"

All works extremely well, including bibliography, sections and figure links. However, for some images, I would like to use absolute sizes in characters like height:5em in HTML instead of relative sizes width:50%.
How can I achieve this? It seems that make4ht can easily produce all relative (Gin-percent option) or all absolute (Gin-dim option) images sizes, but not a mix.
One way that can work in my case would be to use height instead of width in some figures. When the converted finds \includegraphics[height=...] it would use the absolute size, while when it finds \includegraphics[width=...] it would use relative sizes.
Or better, one could have the converter detect when \includegraphics contains something like 0.5\textwidth or specific units like 10em or 20pt and would preserve the intended scaling.
It seems that this could be doable by modifying the function (taken from here) used by style=... below, but I am unable to figure out how to do it
\Preamble{xhtml} 
    \makeatletter 
        \ExplSyntaxOn 
            \Configure{Gin-dim} 
                {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,2)}\char_generate:nn { `\% } { 12 }"} 
        \ExplSyntaxOff 
    \makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble

Here is an attempt, following some hints by @michal, but it throws several error messages
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\Preamble{xhtml} 
    \makeatletter 
        \ExplSyntaxOn 
            \Configure{Gin-dim} 
                \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\Gin@req@width <0.4\textwidth}}%
                {%
                    {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\f@size)}rem"}%
                }
                {%
                    {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,2)}\char_generate:nn { `\% } { 12 }"}%
                }
        \ExplSyntaxOff 
    \makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble


There are missing braces  in  \Configure{Gin-dim} in your edit. I've updated my answer with a fixed code, which uses internal LaTeX commands instead of the ifthen package.

Fantastic @michal.h21 you are so helpful! Thank you very much

Edit:
You can also decide which units to use by testing the image width:
\Preamble{xhtml} 
    \makeatletter 
        \ExplSyntaxOn 
            \Configure{Gin-dim}{ 
                \dim_compare:nTF{\Gin@req@width <0.4\textwidth}%
                {%
                    {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\f@size)}rem"}%
                }
                {%
                    {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,2)}\char_generate:nn { `\% } { 12 }"}%
                }}
        \ExplSyntaxOff 
    \makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble


For this MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}


\end{document}

it produces this HTML:
<!-- l. 5 --><p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='width:10rem' />
</p><!-- l. 7 --><p class='indent'>   <img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='width:50%' />
</p>

Orignal answer:
I would add an extra variant of \includegraphics, \absincludegraphics for this purpose. You can add it to a custom package, mygraphicx.sty:
\ProvidesPackage{mygraphicx}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\absincludegraphics[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
\endinput

It doesn't do anything interesting on its own, but it enables us to redefine it for TeX4ht in mygraphicx.4ht:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\absincludegraphics[2][]{%
\begingroup
% Configure Gin-dim to calculate width of the image by the current font size
\Configure{Gin-dim}
   {\if:boundingbox{style="max-width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\f@size)}rem"}{}}
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
\endgroup
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Hinput{mygraphicx}
\endinput

In the redefinition, we locally configure the Gin-dim configuration to calculate the width of the image by dividing it by the current font size. We can then use the rem units based on the HTML page's main font size.
You can compile your file with the "Gin-percent" option to use the width in percentage by default:
 $ make4ht -m draft filename.tex "Gin-percent"

Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mygraphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}

\absincludegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}


\end{document}

It produces a following HTML:
!-- l. 5 --><p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='max-width:50%' />
</p><!-- l. 7 --><p class='indent'>   <img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='max-width:17rem' />
</p>



Thanks, this would work, but requires changing the LaTeX files to use \absincludegraphics and load mygraphicx. Can't one do it transparently in the cfg file? Something like \Configure{Gin-dim} {\IfSubStr{\Gin@req@width}{em}{style="width:...\%}{style="width:...rem}}? I am also trying to understand how the config file works... Can one load packages in cfg? Where are they documented?

@divenex it is not possible to detect units used in width, they are converted to points by Grahicx, so they are not available to us. Maybe it could be possible to use absolute sizes only for images above some treshold, like 70% of \textwidth.

@divenex the documentation for cfg files is here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html you can add \RequirePackage before \Preamble.

Following @michal solution, here is an alternative I find more convenient and reliable. It switches between relative and absolute scaling of the figures based on whether I call \includegraphics[...]{...} using either the width=... keyword or the height=....
This is reasonable, because when giving a figure width one typically expresses its size as a fraction of the text width, e.g. width=0.5\textwidth, while height is more conveniently expressed in fixed units e.g. height=3em.
Checking the documentation of the graphicx package here I noticed that when the height is not explicitly given to \includegraphics, the package sets the internal variable \Gin@scaley to an exclamation mark \Gin@exclamation.
Accordingly, following the documentation of the LaTeX3 interface here, I test whether \Gin@scaley is equal to \Gin@exclamation, to switch between relative or absolute scaling.
Here is my modified myconfig.cfg file
\Preamble{xhtml} 
\makeatletter 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
    \Configure{Gin-dim}{ 
        \str_if_eq:NNTF{\Gin@scaley}{\Gin@exclamation}%
        {%
            {style="max-width:\fpeval{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,1)}\c_percent_str"}%
        }
        {%
            {style="max-height:\fpeval{round(\Gin@req@height/\f@size,1)}rem"}%
        }}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble

One has to call make4ht as follows
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg  myfile.tex

Hers is a minimal myfile.tex LaTeX example
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=10em]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}

\end{document}

And the corresponding HTML output
<img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='max-height:10.3rem' /> 
<img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' style='max-width:50%' />

